# Using Grep to get specific entries and ignore others

Tags: command-line, search, grep

is there a way to use grep to ignore lines with 141.8. .. contained in them BUT get lines that have GET? Right now I have this but I must be doing something wrong

`sudo grep -v '^141.8.83.213' && "GET" /home/tsec/prototype/logs/glastopf.log | sort -k4,4 | tac | sort -uk4,4 | sort -k1,2 | tail -n 10 > /home/tsec/prototype/logs/ext$`

This is what the log contains

```
2016-04-20 13:30:59,818 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /favicon.ico on e1f841a092e9:80
2016-04-20 13:31:01,817 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested POST /index on e1f841a092e9:80
2016-04-20 13:31:01,855 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /style.css on e1f841a092e9:80
2016-04-20 13:31:01,883 (glastopf.glastopf) 141.8.83.213 requested GET /favicon.ico on e1f841a092e9:80
2016-04-20 16:39:55,713 (glastopf.glastopf) Initializing Glastopf 3.1.3-dev using "/data/glastopf" as work directory.
2016-04-20 16:39:55,797 (glastopf.glastopf) Connecting to main database with: sqlite:///db/glastopf.db
2016-04-20 16:39:55,834 (glastopf.glastopf) Glastopf started and privileges dropped.
2016-04-20 17:54:33,857 (glastopf.glastopf) 62.210.252.43 requested GET / on de96c7b4104d:80
2016-04-20 17:54:34,101 (glastopf.glastopf) 62.210.252.43 requested GET /HNAP1/ on de96c7b4104d:80
2016-04-20 22:06:20,265 (glastopf.glastopf) Initializing Glastopf 3.1.3-dev using "/data/glastopf" as work directory.
2016-04-20 22:06:20,399 (glastopf.glastopf) Connecting to main database with: sqlite:///db/glastopf.db
2016-04-20 22:06:20,446 (glastopf.glastopf) Glastopf started and privileges dropped.
2016-04-20 22:33:23,136 (glastopf.glastopf) 74.91.23.109 requested GET / on 11bbb1d43c02:80
```

So in the end I want to get the entries that have GET in string but ignore those who have the 141.8.83.213 IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two `grep`s:

```
grep "GET" /home/tsec/prototype/logs/glastopf.log |  grep -vF 141.8.83.213 | ...
```

From [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep.1posix.html):

```
-F    Match using fixed strings. Treat each  pattern  specified  as  a
      string  instead  of  a  regular  expression.  If  an  input line
      contains any of the patterns as a contiguous sequence of  bytes,
      the line shall be matched. A null string shall match every line.

-v    Select  lines not matching any of the specified patterns. If the
      -v option is not specified, selected lines shall be  those  that
      match any of the specified patterns.
```

So `-F` lets us avoid escaping the `.`, which would otherwise match any character. `-v` is the classic way to tell `grep` to invert the match.

Comment: Classic approach and works accross the board :)

Comment: I think that you should explain in your answer that the `-v` option is used to exclude lines.

Comment: This worked thankyou, I was missing the F part on the second grep, what does it mean exactly?

Comment: @firepro20 It tells `grep` to treat the pattern as a fixed string instead of a regular expression. So special characters in the pattern aren't treated specially.

Answer (score 2):

Awk allows for logical operators in regex , so you can say match GET and also those lines that don't contain ip

```
  awk '/GET/&&!/141\.8\.83\.213/' log. txt
```

Comment: In a similar vein, `sed -e '/GET/!d' -e '/141\.8\.83\.213/d'`

Comment: @steeldriver yeah , that's another way to do it. Why not post this as an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Single grep,

```
grep -P '^(?!.*?141\.8\.83\.213).*\bGET\b' file
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xG2xR6/1)